# Ping - Request timed out on a local network

Tags: ip-address, ping, firewall, ipv4, request-timed-out

I'm trying to ping another computer that is connected to the same Wi-Fi network. Pinging to anything else (localhost, website, etc.) works fine. But when I try to ping to the local ip address of my second computer I get a `Request timed out.` message

```
$ ping target_ip

Pinging target_ip with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for target_ip:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

Answer (score 5):

1. Try to ping another device from your local network (pinging localhost or a website is not the same).
2. Try to ping from target_ip to source_ip (opposite direction).

If you have response in any of 2 cases above, check the firewall on your target machine (or as in your case, for Windows, make sure you are connected to Private Network, not Public). And make sure you are trying to ping the proper IP address.

Comment: #2 won't work, I'm connected to Private Network and i am pinging the correct address

Comment: @AlexT Why #2 (pinging source_ip from target_ip) won't work? If it doesn't, then it's either firewall on both source_ip and target_ip, or you don't have connectivity between hosts (layer 5 or lower).

Comment: No solution provided

Answer (score 4):

If you are unable to ping a computer on your network, the reason could be that the firewall on that computer is blocking incoming ICMP (Internet Control Message Protocol) traffic. In this case, you can try enabling the "File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv4-In)" inbound rule in Windows Defender Firewall to allow ping requests.

> Note that enabling this rule may make your computer more vulnerable to
> certain types of attacks, so you should only do so if you trust the
> computers on your network and are comfortable with the increased risk.
> Additionally, if you are using a third-party firewall, the steps may
> be different, so you should consult the documentation for that
> firewall for guidance.

Here are the step-by-step instructions:

1. Open `Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security` on the computer that you are not able to ping. You can do this by searching for "Windows Defender Firewall" in the Start menu and clicking on the corresponding result.
2. In the left pane, click on `Inbound Rules.`
3. Scroll down until you find the `File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv4-In)` rule. This rule is used to allow incoming ICMP traffic, which is what ping uses.
4. Right-click on the rule and select `Enable Rule.`

That's it! Close the window and try pinging the computer again. It should now work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, in my case the problem was- I was not able to ping any website like [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) or any other external IP address. But I was able to ping my own ipv4 address. If you are not able to ping your own ipv4 address then follow this(https://support.logmeininc.com/central/help/why-do-i-get-request-timed-out-when-trying-to-ping-a-computer). And if you are not able to ping external IP address then there are 2 cases,

1. You are connected with the ethernet OR ISP connection. Then Ping will work fine.
2. You are using the mobile hotspot, then try changing the bandwidth to 5GHZ from the mobile phone and connect again.
   It worked for me I hope it will work for you as well.

Comment: It's a different issue with same error message.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR: Turn off all defenders**

I had the same issue and very similar answers above helped but I do want to add something in that I didn't see.

My set up was to try to ping an Oracle linux virtual machine running on windows from my MacBook

When I went to turn off Microsoft Defender Firewall, it was already off because I had a third party firewall turned on. Make sure you turn off third party firewalls on your host machine; in my case it was Kaspersky. Once this is turned off, Microsoft Defender Firewall will turn on. Make sure to turn this off.

After this, it had worked for me but some other advice that I found helpful was to make sure all firewalls were off on MacOS and to reset your router.

Comment: Is that reset necessary? Restart the router worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR: Restart the destination device. If fails restart the router too.**

Request Timed Out message tells your computer waited for the acknowledgment of the ping packets sent to the destination IP for a time but received none.

Common causes for this error are either network configuration errors or firewall blocking.

Since you can ping other addresses from your computer successfully, your local computer network configuration is fine.

You can ping the localhost IP (Loopback address) successfully.  It means the firewall settings on your computer are fine.

So, as Andriy Zavoloka mentioned, I too doubt the Firewall settings on the destination computer. Disable the firewall on the destination computer and try to ping it again from the first device.

Even though you have mentioned you know the destination IP address is correct, I suggest you use the network discovery feature and verify if the DHCP server of your WiFi network didn't assign a different IP address to the second computer.

Sometimes a simple reboot on the second computer can fix the problem.

If the issue persists, I suggest you power off the WiFi router (I assume you have the access) and switch it on after one minute. It will reset the routing table cache on the WiFi router.

Then check for the new IP address assigned to the second computer and Ping that address from your first computer.

I hope it will fix the problem.

[My Reference](https://www.corenetworkz.com/2009/05/request-timed-out.html)

Answer (score -1):

Just turn off the firewall. It is not cable modem router isues and it is not WiFi Router issues.

I suffered this issues for long time when I install kubernetes (kubectl, kubeadm, kubelet, etc).
My computers in the same cluster (or in the network) cannot ping each other.
After I consulte with network expert, I turn the Norton utility off (not just shut down. Go to settings and turn firewall off). Now, all the conmouters can ping each other.

Answer (score -2):

**Note: This make the device vulnerable.**

For windows user, goto Firewall and network protection then under Public network turn off Microsoft Defender Firewall.